# Digital-7 font digit '1' in android dose not work well

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

I'm using the Digital-7 font in an android app for DigitalClock view. app work properly but i have a problem with digit '1'. when this digit shown by clock, it cause other digits at right replaced. i tested this font in MS-Word, it worked fine.

[image]

Pleas help.

OK this is tow captures before and after event.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You must use a **monospaced** font.

Comment: Is there any way to use this special font?

Comment: The usual way... read it from assets and assign it as a TypeFace. `Monospaced` indicates a  font **category** in which each glyph is drawn to occupy the same space (`all glyphs have the same width`).

Comment: Tanks for help. i download mono digital font and problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used monospaced font and It solved.